# Quickblox 2.7 token is required

Tags: ios, session, token, quickblox

I've just updated to version 2.7 of Quickblox SDK.  The documentation states that you no longer need to manage a token, simply initialize the framework in AppDelegate as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [QBSettings setApplicationID:19879];
    [QBSettings setAuthKey:@"xxxxxx"];
    [QBSettings setAuthSecret:@"xxxxxxx"];
    [QBSettings setAccountKey:@"xxxxxx"];


    return YES;
}
```

And then later in the app I try to signup a new user by doing the following:

```
-(void)createNewUser:(NSString *)userName Password:(NSString *)password{
    QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
    user.password = password;
    user.login = userName;
     [QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user)    {     
    [self signInUser:userName Password:password];

   } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

     NSLog(@"Response error = %@", response.error.error.description);
   }];
}
```

But each time I try to sign up the user I get a response from Quickblox saying:

```
[QBCore] Response error reasons: {
      errors =     (
          "Token is required"
      );
}
```

How do I get the token.  The documentation is a little confusing, it talks about starting a session with an existent Quickblox token, but doesn't describe how to create or aquire a token.

I've tried adding:

```
QBASesssion *sesssion = [QBASession new]; 
       [QBASession currentSession] startSessionWithDetails:session updateSessionBlock: {
}
```

But I think that method is for using existing tokens.

Answer (score -1):

Please create issue on [github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues) and attach full logs from the start of the app till this error.